# Noun for the desire to sleep?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I have had this thought on many sleepless nights: is there a word specifically for the desire to go to sleep? Not in the sense of being sleepy or tired, but actively wanting to become asleep.

If a person is in bed desiring and attempting to will themselves to sleep. Does this desire have a name?

Comment: *Somnorexia* could be the word.

Comment: Isn't that kind of the definition of insomnia?

Comment: *A consummation devoutly to be wished?*

Answer (score 1):

One of the definitions of Somnolence.

Comment: Yes. It's a nuisance that some other senses suggest that one would have no such desire, particularly that of sleeping for an unusually long time, but one sense does match the question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Google has hits for 'hypnophilia', a coinage allegedly meaning 'a simple love for sleep'.   But that sounds more descriptive of a general feelgood attitude towards sleeping, rather than the anxious wish for sleep at a time when sleep won't come.

And OED doesn't list 'hypnophilia', though it has 'hypnophobia/hypnophoby' for the reverse, 'a morbid dread of falling asleep'.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding this is not what you want:

*Narcolepsy*, according an Oxford dictionary, is

> a condition characterized by an extreme tendency to fall asleep whenever in relaxing surroundings

and according to Cambridge, is

> a medical condition which makes you go to sleep suddenly and when you do not expect it

Comment: No, the OP requested a noun that means one desires to go to sleep. What you have responded with is not subject to volition; it just happens, no matter whether one wants it to or not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I should post this as a comment to the question?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly do that, although I am not sure how to do so in a way that requests clarification on or sheds light upon the question asked. But feel free to try.

Comment: _Narcolepsy_ is in fact more or less an exact **antonym** to what is being asked here: it’s falling asleep without wanting to, rather than wanting to fall asleep and being unable to.